# Conditional Format IF Blank by 1st of Month

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a Google sheet to track payments for a team. I want a cell to turn red if a value hasn't been entered by the 1st of the month. I have 2 other formats already set up to change to green or yellow depending on full payment or partial payment.

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 1):

If a payment has not been received on an transaction by the first day of the following month, you want the payment cell to appear red.

Assume:

- Column A = Transaction date
- Column B = Transaction value
- Column C = Amount received.

Use this formula as a "custom formula" for Column C in Conditional formatting.
`=and(isblank(C2),today()>EOMONTH(A2,0)+1)`

Explanation:

- `AND()` Returns TRUE, if both expressions are true
- `isblank()` - checks that no payment has been received; returns TRUE/FALSE
- `today()>EOMONTH(A2,0)+1)` - is todays date grater than the first day of the month following the transaction date. TRUE/FALSE